# Where is Facelets?

Tags: java, facelets

I am trying to use Facelets with MyFaces 1.2. It appears as though the Facelets download at http://facelets.dev.java.net no longer exists.

Does anyone know 1) where I can download Facelets? 2) why has Facelets been removed from this site? e.g. has it been integrated into JSF 2.0 or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `https://*.dev.java.net` sites have been migrated to `http://*.java.net` at December 2010. So the Facelets project home page is now available at http://facelets.java.net, liks as that the Mojarra home page is now available at http://javaserverfaces.java.net.

However, it's true that you can't download Facelets 1.x from there anymore. You can however still download it from several online code repositories such as Maven [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.facelets/jsf-facelets) or [here](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/thirdparty-releases/com.sun.facelets/jsf-facelets). The last one has currently [1.1.15](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/thirdparty-releases/com.sun.facelets/jsf-facelets/1.1.15) which was the latest release of Facelets 1.x.

And yes, since JSF 2.0, Facelets has been integrated into the JSF API to replace JSP as default view technology. Facelets is now maintained as part of JSF specification. Endusers are encouraged to use the new JSF 2.x instead of the dead JSF 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make use of Maven to fetch and maintain your dependencies.

You can add the following profile to your settings.xml (Note that this is nested xml):

```
....
<profile>
    <id>java-net</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>Repo ID</id>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <name>Java.net Maven repo</name>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

    </profile>
        ...
```

and in your individual projects build file(s) (also nested):

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
...
```

Maven not only makes it easy to locate and manage dependencies, but also abstracts your project from an IDE if using one.